# Can't import a file on prod (Symfony 3.4)

Tags: apache, symfony

I'm configuring a website on prod and there is a part where I need to import a file.

So I have a page with a form that asks me to import the file, and in dev it works.
Now the problem is that, in prod environment, when I submit the form I get an error 500 like so :
[image: The said error]

How could I resolve this?

Edit :

Here is the line I found in the log file :

```
[2020-02-19 13:26:53] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\Exception\FileException: "Unable to write in the "csv/" directory" at /var/www/html/******/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/File.php line 115 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\File\\Exception\\FileException(code: 0): Unable to write in the \"csv/\" directory at /var/www/html/******/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/File.php:115)"} []
[2020-02-19 13:26:53] cache.WARNING: Failed to save key "%5BSymfony%5CBundle%5CTwigBundle%5CController%5CExceptionController%5D%5B1%5D" (array) {"key":"%5BSymfony%5CBundle%5CTwigBundle%5CController%5CExceptionController%5D%5B1%5D","type":"array","exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): file_put_contents(/var/www/html/******/var/cache/prod/pools/kdBlscBHv1/5e4d379d6cc116.53694267): failed to open stream: Permission denied at /var/www/html/******/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Cache/Traits/FilesystemCommonTrait.php:87)"} []
```

Here is the function I use when the file has been submitted and approved (few validity tests) :

```
private function uploadCsvFile($file)
    {
        $ext = "csv";
        $originalFilename = pathinfo($file->getClientOriginalName(), PATHINFO_FILENAME);
        
        $safeFilename = transliterator_transliterate('Any-Latin; Latin-ASCII; [^A-Za-z0-9_] remove; Lower()', $originalFilename);
        $newFilename = $safeFilename.'-'.uniqid().'.'.$ext;
        // Move the file to the directory where csv files are stored
        try 
        {
            $directory = 'csv/';
            $file->move($directory, $newFilename);
            return $directory.$newFilename;
        } 
        catch (FileException $e) 
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

EDIT 2:

I managed to resolve it. I had to give writing rights to everyone on the folder (I used this command : **chmod 777 my_folder**)

Comment: Please check the error logs on your server. There should be some kind of critical error when this happens. Have you tried running the prod-environment on your local machine?

Comment: I tried but I didn't find anything that helped me

Comment: Search for `php.CRITICAL` in there or for a common word like "fatal" (as in fatal error) or "exception". If you don't see anything in there, we can not help you. You must get to some kind of error message or be able to reproduce the issue locally in your dev environment. The 500 internal server error is just a very generic description, that the issue happened server side, i.e. somewhere in your PHP code.

Comment: Sorry to keep bothering you, but the code by itself is still not enough. We do not know if the error even occurs in there or somewhere else. Even if it happens inside that action it could be any of the function calls that trigger the error, e.g. what about the try catch not catching the right exception? `pathinfo()` might return a wrong value (not a string), causing the subsequent code to fail. etc. pp. There is really no way for us to tell what causes the error here without a proper error message and/or stack trace.

Comment: Now you can see the last lines I got in the prod.log file

Comment: The message says: Unable to write in the "csv/" directory. Did you make sure the directory exists? You probably can use the [Filesystem-component's mkdir()](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/filesystem.html#mkdir) for this.

Comment: Yeah it already exists

Comment: You are using a relative path in your code. Maybe change it to  an absolute path, e.g. something like `/var/www/my-app/csv`, to make sure the location matches. If that works, check the permissions. Depending on your system set up you might have different php/apache users that require you to `chmod`/`chown` the directory accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

My only idea is that you should make sure that the server has rights to write in the csv directory, if the DEV environment is working check if the owner of csv is www-data or w/e the default apache user is called on your server OS is called. You should make sure to set the read/write permissions